# DOMXpath can't get inside text

Tags: php, tags, domdocument, domxpath

I have an HTML file like this above:

```
<div class = "lvlone">
    <div class = "lvltwo">
        <span>Hello</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to get the "Hello" string
I tried this `$res = $xpath->query("//div[@class='lvlone']/div[@class='lvltwo']/span");`
but nothing!
Any ideas?
Thanks anyway.

Comment: Do you want to parse how page or just 1-2 strings(tags)?

Comment: for one now! but i am intresting for multiple too if u know the answer!

Answer (score 1):

It works. try this

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML('<div class = "lvlone">
    <div class = "lvltwo">
        <span>Hello</span>
    </div>
</div>');
$x = new DOMXPath($dom);
$entries = $x->query("//div[@class='lvlone']/div[@class='lvltwo']/span");
foreach ($entries as $entry)
  var_dump($entry->nodeValue);

 //Output - string 'Hello' (length=5)
```

Comment: Yes u are right! it was a simple mistake in my code! Thanks for ur time anyway!

Comment: @Manos - You should mark this answer as your accepted answer by clicking the checkmark to the left of the post.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to parse how HTML page I suggest you to use this:
http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net

Simplehtmldom is PHP class which parse how web page content and gives you ability to search and find by defferent parameters.. (tags, class, id, etc..)